# Loading of Images is taking too much time

Tags: php, html, css

This is my code for loading the image in index.php page from database.

```
<div id=images>
    <h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1> //Title coming from database table
    <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>"> //Image url coming from database table
    <hr/>
</div>
```

and I have created an external css file style.css which is as follows:

```
#images img {
    width:100%;
}
```

I have total of 20-25 images (each of approx 30-35 KB) in this page and the average loading time of each image is 1 second which causes the complete webpage to open in approx 25-30 seconds.

Same thing is being used in one of my competitor's website with same amount of images (each of approx above 100 KB) is having approx loading time of each image about 0.13 second.

As per my analysis the problem is with the code of images only. Please help me on this with your valuable answers.

Comment: The images are hosted on your server or on `third party` websites?

Comment: @FaresM. On my own hosting.

Comment: Are you using `gzip compression`?

Comment: @FaresM. No, I haven't used any compression

Comment: Can you share the `url` of your page ?

Comment: @FaresM. Coz of some security reasons, I will not be able to share the URL. :(

Comment: GZipping images will not yield any advantage, unless you have a bunch of old-school BMPs.

Comment: Have you made sure you're NOT using cache when comparing the two sites? Could it be you've already visited and cached the competitors site before? I hardly doubt that loading 10 images with 100kb each is faster than loading 10 images with 30kb each.

Comment: @IkoTikashi I am comparing both the site using www.pagescoring.com. The result of my competitor's website is http://www.pagescoring.com/website-speed-test/?url=http%3A%2F%2Findoredefenceacademy.co.in%2F

His average time is 4sec approx and mine is 25+

Comment: So, have you made sure it's not the database query taking too long?

Comment: @IkoTikashi Yeah I am sure its the images problem. My database query is fine.

Comment: How long does your db-query take?

Comment: @IkoTikashi only 235ms

Comment: Must be your hosting provider then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Maybe your server upload speed too slow 
2) Compress images

Comment: I am not having any issues with uploading.
Image size is already kept at minimum of approx 30KB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to use web pages with deflate encoded content:

```
<?php 
    if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) 
        ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); 
    else ob_start(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use caching for this
Here are the links
[Cache For Php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Comment: That's serverside caching. The user would still need to load those images